# NATでセキュリティレベルが向上するのはなぜ？

Tags: network, security

NATについて授業を受け、その中でNATを使う利点に

1. IPv4の枯渇問題へ対処できる
2. 一か所にIPアドレスの設定が集中しておりISPの移行などが容易
3. 内部ローカルアドレスが隠蔽できるのでセキュリティレベルが上昇する

という3つが上げられました。
最初2つは理解できるのですが、3つ目の「セキュリティレベルが上昇する」とはどういう意味なのでしょうか？

僕の認識では、そもそも内部ローカルアドレスでは外部グローバルアドレスと通信できないので、セキュリティレベルが上昇する以前の問題があるように感じました。

またNATを使わない状態で、内部ローカルアドレスが分かったとして、そこへどのようにアクセスされてセキュリティの問題が生じるのでしょうか？内部ローカルアドレスが分かったところで大して問題がないと感じてしまいます。

Answer (score 3):

NAT と書かれていますが NAPT と読み替えることにして

「上昇する」という文言からは、「前」と「後」があって後のほうが良いというニュアンスが読み取れます。この場合「後」は [NAPT 導入後] なのでしょうが、さて「前」は一体どういう状況なのか？　読者はその授業を直接受けたわけではないので推定するしかないですね。

「前」が [NAPT 導入前] であるなら：

質問の文言からは内部マシンにはローカルアドレスを使うのが前提であり、決してグローバル IP アドレスを使うことは無いと仮定しているようですが NAPT なしで組織内マシンから組織外へ通信するには、組織内マシンにもグローバル IP アドレスを振らざるを得ないわけです。よって

- 前：内部の PC が使っているグローバル IP アドレスが、外部から推測でき、かつ組織外から当該マシンに直接アクセス可能
- 後：内部の PC のローカル IP アドレスが推測できても NAPT するルータに阻まれアクセスできない

ということでセキュリティは増すでしょう。
講師がそういう意味で言っていたのかは読者にはわからないですけど。

Answer (score 1):

> 僕の認識では、そもそも内部ローカルアドレスでは外部グローバルアドレスと通信できないので、
> セキュリティレベルが上昇する以前の問題があるように感じました。

一般的に、内部ローカルアドレスから、外部グローバルアドレスと通信する場合、ゲートウェイを通して通信します。
NATというのは内部ローカルアドレスと外部グローバルアドレスを変換する仕組みです。

従いまして、外部グローバルアドレスと通信できないことはありません。
これは、内部ローカルアドレスから、外部グローバルアドレスへは通信でき、
そのアンサーを受信することはできますが、外部から、内部への直接の通信はできません。
外部からは１つのIPアドレスはわかっていますが、その内部には複数のPCがつながり、
それぞれに、内部ローカルアドレスを持っていますが、それは外部からは見えません。
従いまして、外部からのアタックには強いといえます。

> 内部ローカルアドレスが分かったとして、そこへどのようにアクセスされてセキュリティの問題が生じる
> のでしょうか？内部ローカルアドレスが分かったところで大して問題がないと感じてしまいます。

まず、何らかの攻撃がされる場合と、全くされない場合ではどちらが問題ないといえるでしょうか？
何らかの攻撃の有効性にもよりますが、OSにはいろいろなセキュリティホールがあり、そこをついて攻撃してくる可能性があります。この攻撃が有効な場合、パスワード、クレジットカード
情報等が盗まれたり、データを消去されたりする可能性があります。
全く攻撃されない場合は、安全といえます。

現実問題として、どこかのサイトのユーザー情報が盗まれたり、クレジットカード情報が盗まれたりしていますよね。
これはセキュリティホールをついて攻撃しているわけです。
いろいろなWEBサイトは固定のグローバルアドレスが割り当てられていますので、攻撃する
側から見れば、好都合な訳です。

こちらも参照してみてください。
https://www.infraexpert.com/study/ip10.html